# jquery ajax send string as POST

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am developping a wordpress plugin, want to send string as post ajax parameters, but the string breaks with '&'
code is

```
var data = "http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1&setval=RFZ83WSXa816yc6DNcgfHlgIkztR7KEC6JHRHCCcwfw|~HBZW9j3B59f8rCXO_QLY-gG2MDAcKo6fKG2AnbYnMns|~KA1KUT_SuU9W2UDTnngTsbJiptTvGWZAAzTfN5BCHak|~1";

$.ajax({
           data: data
           type: "POST",
           url: '<?php echo plugins_url().'/page-loader/createMetaDetails.php'; ?>',
           data :data,
           success: function(msg){
             alert('wow'+msg);
           }
         });
```

it is not working only passing till 'http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1', why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put data in key value pair array to pass [**jquery ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function.

change

```
var data = 'http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1&setval=RFZ83WSXa816yc6DNcgfHlgIkztR7KEC6JHRHCCcwfw|~HBZW9j3B59f8rCXO_QLY-gG2MDAcKo6fKG2AnbYnMns|~KA1KUT_SuU9W2UDTnngTsbJiptTvGWZAAzTfN5BCHak|~1'
```

To

```
var data = { yoururl:'http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=1&setval=RFZ83WSXa816yc6DNcgfHlgIkztR7KEC6JHRHCCcwfw|~HBZW9j3B59f8rCXO_QLY-gG2MDAcKo6fKG2AnbYnMns|~KA1KUT_SuU9W2UDTnngTsbJiptTvGWZAAzTfN5BCHak|~1'}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `data` property should be a Javascript object in key:value format; the keys will be the form field names.